# Countable set in a Banach space which spans densely?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $\mathcal{C}(\mathbf{T})$ be the algebra of continuous complex functions on the unit circle $\mathbf{T}$. Consider the following two statements:

- The $*$-subalgebra generated by $1$ and $z$ spans densely (by the Stone--Weierstrass Theorem).
- Every $f\in \mathcal{C}(\mathbf{T})$ can be written as a uniform limit $f(z) = \sum_{n\in \mathbf{Z}} \lambda_n z^n$ for some appropriate coefficients $\lambda_n \in \mathbf{C}$.

Is the second obvious from the first? The first statement means that every $f$ can be written as $f = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n$ where the $f_n$'s are Laurent polynomials, but should it be clear that the $f_n$'s have the *specific* form $f_n = \sum_{i=-n}^n \lambda_i z^i$?

---

Maybe more generally, suppose $X$ is a Banach space with $X=\overline{\mathrm{span}}\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ for some countable set $\{x_n\}$. Then can we write each $x\in X$ as $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_nx_n$ for some appropriate coefficients $\lambda_n$?

Frequently I see arguments passing from a dense subspace to all of $X$ using this kind of argument: do it for finite linear combinations, and then extend to "infinite sums" by density. But I'm not sure how that works unless each element is indeed a "series" of the form $\sum \lambda_n x_n$.

In a Hilbert space it's true if $\{x_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis ... in that case we can take $\lambda_n = \langle x,x_n\rangle$. But that uses the additional structure of a Hilbert space.

---

Here is some context for this question. The **Cuntz algebra** $\mathcal{O}_1$ is the universal C*-algebra generated by a single unitary $s$. I'm trying to prove that $\mathcal{O}_1$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}(\mathbf{T})$ via $s\mapsto \iota$, where $\iota(z):=z$. I have a $*$-homomorphism $\varphi:\mathcal{O}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{C}(\mathbf{T})$ given by $s\mapsto \iota$, and I'm trying to show it's injective. It clearly hits all Laurent polynomials, which are dense in $\mathcal{C}(\mathbf{T})$. So if I can show it's injective, it's isometric and so its image is simultaneously closed and dense, hence this map is surjective.

I've managed to show $\mathcal{O}_1$ is spanned densely by $\{s^n : n\in \mathbf{Z}\}$, but that doesn't mean that each element of $\mathcal{O}_1$ has the form
$$x = \sum_{n\in \mathbf{Z}} \lambda_n s^n$$
does it? In this particular case, maybe it does. If I can get that to work I'm done.

(The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_C*-algebra) uses the fact that $C^*(s) \simeq \mathcal{C}(\sigma(s))$ by the functional calculus. There is another argument using the gauge invariant uniqueness theorem from graph C*-algebras, but that sounds like a big hammer for a tiny bug ...)

Comment: No, the second is not true. The Fourier series does not converge uniformly in general. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series

Comment: @orangeskid: So that means you can't do it by taking $\lambda_n$ to be the Fourier coefficients, but how do you know there is not some other sequence $\lambda_n$ that works?

Comment: @NateEldredge If a sequence $\lambda_n$ works (for uniform convergence, for example), they have to be the Fourier coefficient (simply take the usual inner product with the functions $z^n$).

Comment: @Ehsaan: There is the notion of a Schauder basis http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis; not every separable Banach space has one, although all ''common'' separable ones do.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: Great question. If a series $\sum f_n$  converges   to $f$ then $\sum (f_n, g) $ converges to $(f,g)$. Taking $g=e_n$ will  produce a series with only one non-zero term $\lambda_n$  (at most) so this must be $(f,e_n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a theorem (paraphrased) from Ivan Singer's *Bases in Banach Spaces, Vol. 1* (Springer-Verlag 1970). In what follows, "basis" means "Schauder basis".

Proposition 4.3 (pg. 29):

Let $E$ be a Banach space with a bounded  basis $\{x_i\}$. Let $\{\alpha_i\}$ be a sequence of non-zero scalars and for each positive integer $n$, let $$y_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i.$$ Then $\{y_i\}$ is a basis of $E$ if and only if $\sup\limits_{n} {\Vert y_n\Vert\over|\alpha_{n+1}|}<\infty$.

Note $(y_n,y_n^*)\subset X\times X^*$ is   a complete biorthogonal  system ("biorthogonal" means $y_i^*y_j=\delta_{ij}$; "complete" means the linear span of $\{y_n\}$ is dense) where $y_n^*={1\over\alpha_n }x_n^* -{1\over\alpha_{n+1}}x_{n+1}^*$.

It then follows from the above  that in any infinite dimensional Banach space with a basis, there is   biorthogonal system $(y_i,y_i^*)\subset X\times X^*$with $\{ y_i\}$ complete 
that is not a basis of the space.

For a complete biorthogonal system $(y_i,y_i^*)$, your condition would imply $\{y_i\}$ is basic; so the above furnishes   counterexamples to your conjecture for infinite dimensional spaces with a basis. (Such counterexamples exist in separable Banach spaces without bases as well: every Banach space has a complete biorthogonal system).

For a concrete example, take $X=\ell_1$ and for each $n$, $y_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n e_k$ where $e_k$ is the standard $k$th unit vector in $\ell_1$. Then $\{y_n\}$ is not a basis of $\ell_1$, though its linear span is dense in $\ell_1$ (the linear span contains the unit vectors).

The proof that this is so follows more easily from the following characterization of bases:

If $\{x_i\}$ is a complete set of non-zero vectors in the Banach space $X$, then $\{x_i\}$  is a basis of $X$ if and only if there is a $K>0$ such that for any sequence of scalars $\{\alpha_i\}$ and any $m<n$ one has $\Bigl\Vert \sum\limits_{k=1}^m \alpha_k x_k\Bigr\Vert \le K \Bigl\Vert \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \alpha_k x_k\Bigr\Vert$.

(Note $\Vert y_n\Vert_{\ell_1}=n$ and $\Vert y_n-y_{n+1}\Vert_{\ell_1}=1$.)

The proofs of the above statements can be found in Singer. 
Singer's book may be hard to find; but you should be able to find  most of these results, and other results which imply a negative answer to your general question,  in any text covering Schauder bases in detail. E.g., Kalton and Albiac's text *Topics in Banach Space Theory* or Megginson's text *An Introduction to Banach Space theory*.

For your first question, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695421/how-to-show-that-the-monomials-are-not-a-schauder-basis-for-c0-1).