# $\{x^k\}^\infty_{k=0}$ is not basis in $C[0;1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

$\{x^k\}^\infty_{k=0}$ is not basis in $C[0;1]$.

I know how to show that a system of functions is basis if it is orthogonal (Parseval's identity), but I do not understand how to show it for arbitrary system.

Possibly, we should find a continuous function that has some problems with approximation with an infinite sum of monomials, but I have no idea what contradiction we need to obtain.

Comment: Like, a Hamel basis? Anything that's not a polynomial will not be in the span of those vectors. For example, anything with infinitely many roots.

Comment: The answers here might be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695421/how-to-show-that-the-monomials-are-not-a-schauder-basis-for-c0-1

Comment: Assume a basis should be finitely linear combinated to form every continuous  function on [0, 1], then exp(x) is not the case, since it is an infinite power series.

Comment: You should mention the definition of the basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ be normed space. The system of elements $\{f_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ is a basis for $F$, if for every $f\in F$
$$f=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \alpha_k f_k:=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{N} \alpha_k f_k,$$
and this representation is unique, where by convergence we mean convergence in norm.

The system of functions you gave is not a basis in $C[0;1]$. Indeed, if one wrote that $$f=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_k x^k,$$
for given $f\in C[0;1]$, he would obtain that $f$ is infinitely differentiable. Obviously, it isn't true for any given continuous function.

Comment: You should also mention the definition of the basis.

Answer (score 1):

The subspace $P[0,1]$ generated by $\{x_k\}_{k=0}^\infty$  consists of the polynomials. So all you need to do is show that there are functions in $C[0,1]$ that are not polynomials.

You can do this by constructing a nonzero function with infinitely many zeroes. Or by considering $f(x)=\sqrt x$, which is not differentiable at zero. Any function that is not infinitely differentiable will do.

One might be tempted to write "infinite sums" (i.e., series). It is very important to understand that a series is **not** a sum, but a limit of sums; and talking about "limit" implies that we have a metric or at least a topology. With $C[0,1]$, the usual metric is the one given by the uniform norm.

Now, this is interesting: if we consider all uniformly convergent series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$, the set of functions we obtain is the set of *analytic* functions $A[0,1]$. On the other hand, the closure of $P[0,1]$ is all of $C[0,1]$ via [Weierstrass' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: Why the function $f(x) = 0$ isn't a polynomial? Just set all coefficients to zero.

Comment: And where did I say such thing?

Comment: "So all you need to do is show that there are functions in C[0,1]
 that are not polynomials.

You can do this by constructing a function with infinitely many zeroes."

Comment: There, I added the implicit "nonzero".