# Uniform convergence of power series to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

I was reading one of the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695421/how-to-show-that-the-monomials-are-not-a-schauder-basis-for-c0-1), and got stuck on the following point.

Let $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k$ be a power series that converges uniformly to $0$ on $[0,1]$.

**Question:** Then is it true that $a_k=0$ for all $k$?

I'm probably missing something obvious, and would appreciate a hint. So far I just see that if we call the partial sums $P_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $n_\varepsilon$ such that
$$\|P_{n_\varepsilon}-0\|_\infty=\|P_{n_\varepsilon}\|_\infty\leq\varepsilon.$$
But is this enough to conclude that the $a_k$ are all $0$?

Comment: It follows from the unicity of the Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's denote the power series by $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_kx^k$, because $f(x)$ converge in $x=1$, by a claim i will prove at the end of the answer, it is converging uniformly in $[-r,r]$ for $0\leq r<1$, thus we can conclude that f(x) is differentiable in $0$ infinitely many times. because it is differentiable the derivative is equal to the directional derivative, so we can conclude that $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{0-0}{x-0}=0$. for every $0<x<1$ we know that $f^{(n)}(x)=0$, so by the same reasoning as before we can conclude that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$. now, $f(x)$ is analytic on $(-1,1)$ we can conclude that it's power representation is it's taylor series,  and we will get that the coefficients are $a_k=\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}=0$.

**proof of the claim:** i will prove that if a power $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$ is converging in $x_0$ then it is converging uniformly and absolutely in $[-r,r]$ for $0\leq r<|x_0|$.

because the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx_0^k$ is converging, then $a_kx_0^k\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}{}0$, thus this sequence is bounded. let us denote $\sup_k|a_kx_0^k|=M$. let $0\leq r<|x_0|$, and $q=\frac{r}{|x_0|}$, then $|q|<1$ and for all $x$ such that $|x|\leq r$
$$
|a_kx^k|=|a_kx_0^k|\cdot|\left(\frac{x}{x_0}\right)^k|\leq Mq^k
$$

because the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty Mq^k$ is convergent, then by weierstrass M test the original power series is converging uniformly and absolutely in $[−r,r]$.

Comment: The function defined by the series is equal to zero on $[0, 1]$, which is clearly a smooth function.

Comment: clearly smooth in what domain? i argued that it is also smooth in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Yes, you're right but I don't understand how you conclude that $f$ converge uniformly on $[-r, r]$ from the simple convergence in $1$?

Comment: I think to conclude that the series converges in $[-,r,r]$ you need absolute convergence of $\sum a_k$.

Comment: it follows from follows from weierstrass M test. i will edit my answer to clarify it. thank you for the remarks.

Comment: Hmm isn't it enough to do this on the open interval $(0,1)$ and conclude the same thing, i.e. $a_k=0$ from the formula for the coefficients?

Comment: @geometricK, sure it should work. Actually the proof of the unicity of the Taylor expansion still works at 0 even if the series does not convergence on a neighbourhood of the origin. You just have to consider right limits everywhere.